# How to remove the line (empty) of a pivot table?

Tags: excel, pivot-table

How to remove the line (empty) of a pivot table?

It always appear, the line doesn't has any value, but I have a lot of empty cells.

How to make a pivot table without the line (empty)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In PIVOTTABLE TOOLS, tab ANALYZE > Data, Change Data Source ensure the Table/Range only extends as far as your raw data does (eg do not include entire columns).

Or, apply a filter to your Row Labels column in the PT and deselect (blank).

Or, if the (empty) cells are in the VALUES field you would need to filter these out or move the related raw data outside the selected Table/Range.

Comment: The table/range need to be extended to the empty data, and the empty cells are on the line field :/

Comment: Here is my pivot table http://imagizer.imageshack.us/v2/280x200q90/674/q2SG0j.png

Comment: The first line is the empty line, and i dont wanna this line there D:

Comment: oh srry, try this one https://imagizer.imageshack.us/v2/293x395q90/674/q2SG0j.png

Comment: And the empty line is appearing here https://imagizer.imageshack.us/v2/982x349q90/673/YmfACu.png
in the first column

Comment: I miss that, thx man, you save my day